# What is the error?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

This is my line of code

```
int a[9] = { −2, 1, −3, 4, −1, 2, 1, −5, 4 } ;
```

And this is my error "parse error before character 0342".

Tried this as well but same error

```
int a[] = { −2, 1, −3, 4, −1, 2, 1, −5, 4 } ;
```

I'm using Sublime Text. g++ compiler

Comment: You may have some unprintable character in that line.  Unless you have a tool for viewing binary digits, I'd try retyping the line from scratch.

Comment: Have you tried to retype the entire line?  There may be an invisible character.

Comment: Yes that did it. Thank you! I am such a noob.. I had copy pasted the numbers from my problem statement so I guess that's where the error was. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using a correct minus character. Replace yours: − to this one: -

Answer (score 0):

Hi has to do with some weird encoding of your source code, just replace your source code array declaration with this:

```
  int a[9]={-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4};
```